# Don't know how to write the name of file in bash

Tags: linux, windows, bash

So in linux i simply write this :

```bsh
for((i=1; i<=100; ++i)); do
  echo $i
  ./gen $i > input
  ./a < input > out1
  ./brute < input > out2
  diff -w out1 out2 || break

done
```

hovewer in windows even when i change the `./gen` to `gen.exe` it shows this error :

```
1
test.sh: line 3: gen.exe: command not found
test.sh: line 4: a.exe: command not found
test.sh: line 5: brute.exe: command not found
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Can you please edit your question and add the script / bat file you use in Windows? Do `gen.exe`, `a.exe` and `brute.exe` exist in your Windows in the first place? Are they in %PATH%? Please don't answer with a comment, but update your question.

Comment: I didn't mean by gen.exe as an "big" program it's just a compiled c++ file, i have all that files in the same directory (obviously including the .sh file).

Comment: If you'd be kind and post your Windows script.. it's impossible to troubleshoot something you don't see. On the same go, `dir` and `%PATH%`-outputs could also help. Some applications use a special `%PATH%`, if your compiler is one of them knowing that also helps.

Comment: The windows script it's the same , but i'll edit my post.

Comment: When you say 'in Windows' do you mean WSL or Cygwin, or something?

Comment: I am guessing that you are new to programming and are writing code intended for Linux/Unix on your windows box?  We can help you FOR SURE but we need a lot more information.  What are you attempting to do (big picture), where is your code coming from?  How are you compiling it? etc etc.. please fill us in.  I am guessing that you will want to add WSL and a distro to your windows installation but there is no way to know without the details.